# How to remove change language key button from keyboard in iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, keyboard, key

I want to remove **change language key** from my keyboard in **iOS** app with **Swift3**.[image]

Comment: You can't make any changes to the standard keyboards.

Comment: I want to user just can using English keyboard no another languages. @rmaddy

Comment: [Edit] your question to make your requirements clear. Instead of asking how to remove the globe key, ask how you ensure a user can only enter English text. Clearly explain your goal and what you are trying to do and why.

Comment: I want to disable other language key in numbers and punctuation keyboard . Any idea how can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Applies for iOS 10 or later)

Swift

Use  .`asciiCapable` for Swift

```
txtField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
```

Objective-C

```
self.txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot remove a specific button from keyboard unless you create a custom keyboard. There are third party custom keyboards available that you can use in your app. You can manage behavior of custom keyboards also.

Another alternate option is: set keyboard type as ASCII Capable.

[image]

You can also set keyboard type programatically:

**Swift 4:**

`yourTextField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable`

**Swift 3:**

`yourTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.asciiCapable`

**Objective C:**

`yourTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable`;

`yourTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation`;

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using:  `yourTextField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable`.

Comment: topTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.asciiCapable